# QFtp not sending packets in wireshark

Tags: c++, qt, qftp

I'm learning about using QFtp.

I'd like to connect to a remote ftp server and list its content.

This what I wrote so far:

```
// libftp.cpp
#include "libftp.h"

libFTP::libFTP(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}

void libFTP::open(QString host)
{
    connect(&ftp,SIGNAL(commandFinished(int,bool)),this,SLOT(status(int,bool)));
    connect(&ftp,SIGNAL(listInfo(QUrlInfo)),this,SLOT(dir(QUrlInfo)));
    ftp.setTransferMode(QFtp::Active);
    ftp.connectToHost(host);
    ftp.list();
    ftp.cd("USER");
}

void libFTP::disconnect()
{
    ftp.abort();
    ftp.deleteLater();
}

void libFTP::download(QString filename)
{
    ftp.get(filename);
}

void libFTP::upload(QString path,QString filename)
{
    QString fullpath=path+filename;
    try
    {
      QFile *f= new QFile(fullpath);
      if(f->exists())
      {
          qDebug()<<"File Trovato";
          ftp.mkdir("test");
          //ftp.put(f,filename);
          f->close();
          f->deleteLater();
      }
    }
    catch(std::exception x)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Errore " << x.what();
    }
}

void libFTP::status(int id,bool error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Errore";
    }
    else
        qDebug()<<"Status ID " << QString(id);
}

void libFTP::dir(QUrlInfo directory)
{
    qDebug()<<directory.name();
}
```

---

```
// libftp.h
#ifndef LIBFTP_H
#define LIBFTP_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QFtp>
#include <QUrlInfo>
class libFTP : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit libFTP(QObject *parent = 0);
    void open(QString host);
    void disconnect();
    void download(QString filename);
    void upload(QString path,QString filename);

   private:
       QFtp ftp;

signals:

public slots:
    void status(int id,bool error);
    void dir(QUrlInfo directory);
};

#endif // LIBFTP_H
```

And I call it from main:

```
#include <libftp.h>
int main()
{
    libFTP *ftp = new libFTP();
    ftp->open("10.20.xx.xxx");
    ftp->deleteLater();
}
```

The server I'm connecting to accepts anonymous login.
When I try to debug this code, I notice that no slots are called and I don't see any FTP packets in my wireshark capture. In every example code I saw that's the way QFtp is used, what am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you separate "files" in your question next time so it is easier to follow.

Comment: here it is, sorry

Comment: I've already done it for you, just keep it in mind next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, that wasn't immediate for a qt newbie, it didn't show any info.
I had to run QFtp in a QApplication. I think this is needed by the event loop

calling QApplication in main() solved it.